# Why do some usernames on FreeBSD start with an underscore?

Tags: freebsd, users

Some usernames on FreeBSD start with an underscore:

```
_dhcp:*:65:65:dhcp programs:/var/empty:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

but others do not:

```
www:*:80:80:World Wide Web Owner:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

What's the significance of this underscore? Is it purely historical or does it serve a practical purpose?

Some more examples can be seen in the FreeBSD [ports/UIDs](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/blob/master/UIDs) file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be more than one case, but the one you point out was discussed in a mailing-list thread *[ISC DHCP Server port UID/GID question](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2008-January/046433.html)* in 2008, where the `_dhcp` user was known to be a special account (with different privileges from the daemon):

```
  I noticed that, but I believe that that is a privilege separation 
account that is used with the OpenBSD-version of the dhclient. Also, as 
I pointed out, if this is usable, then why isn't the isc-dhcp-server 
port using it instead of allocating a UID/GID for itself during the install?

Erik

Florent Thoumie wrote:
> On Jan 18, 2008 12:01 PM, Erik Van Benschoten <evanben at valleycomnet.com> wrote:
>> Greetings,
>>
>>   Is there a specific reason that the port of the ISC's DHCP server does
>> not seem to have/use a registered UID/GID?
> 
> Maybe because there's already _dhcp user (uid 65) in base?
```

Checking my FreeBSD 10 machine, I see another account, this one labeled clearly enough:

```
_pflogd:*:64:64:pflogd privsep user:/var/empty:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Further reading:

- [Privilege Separated OpenSSH](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep.html)
- [OpenBSD 3.6 ChangeLog](https://www.openbsd.org/plus36.html)

  > - Have dhclient(8) fall back to user nobody if user _dhcp doesn't exist. Helps with upgrades.
  > - New _dhcp user and group for, funnily enough, the DHCP programs.
- ["user/group _pflogd:_pflogd" what's with the _ ?](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2004-June/030438.html) (freebsd-current mailing list, 2004)
- [pf not logging on 5.3-BETA3 ?](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-pf/2004-September/000463.html) (freebsd-pf mailing list, 2004)

```
    Okay, have you guys read UPDATING?
    > 20040623:
    >         pf was updated to OpenBSD-stable 3.5 and pflogd(8) is privilege
    >         separated now. It uses the newly created "_pflogd" user/group
    >         combination. If you plan to use pflogd(8) make sure to run
    >         mergemaster -p or install the "_pflogd" user and group manually.
```

Comment: It also seems that there's some history behing the `_pflogd` user, too. [A post on the FreeBSD mailing lists](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2004-June/030438.html) says that it's from OpenBSD.

Answer (score 2):

It's related to a OpenBSD convention, mentioned in the book "Absolute OpenBSD, 2nd Edition: Unix for the Practical Paranoid" (p. 103):

> _username
>
> If you take a look at /etc/passwd, you’ll see that many unprivileged
>   users have an underscore before their name, such as _syslogd , _ldapd
>   , and _dhcp .
>
> This is an OpenBSD convention for identifying unprivileged users. Most
>   add-on software also uses unprivileged usernames beginning with an
>   underscore, such as _mysql and _postgresql .
>
> Not all unprivileged usernames start with an underscore, however. Some
>   of these are legacy users that OpenBSD retains for compatibility
>   reasons, such as nobody . Others have a long history or support
>   inflexible software, and changing them would be more annoyance than
>   it’s worth.
>
> The presence of an underscore means that a user is unprivileged. The
>   absence of an underscore means nothing; the user might be a normal or
>   it might be unprivileged. If you create your own unprivileged users,
>   you don’t need to include a leading underscore, but doing so will help
>   other system administrators understand what the user does.

Comment: Related topic on [Debian](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2008/11/msg00343.html)