# What are the different types of users on MacOS X

Tags: osx, users

I am using Mac OS X.

When I go to <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Users & Groups</kbd>, I can see users who can log in to the system, but if I do `dscl . list /users`, it gives a long list of users.

Why are only a few of those listed in <kbd>System Preferences</kbd>? What is the other type of users?

Comment: Apparently you are rather using `MacOS X` (build on top of a `FreeBSD`) rather than `MacOS` (which had not any relation with any Unix).

Comment: If you would like to see what those users do : `dscl . -list /users RealName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at a listing:

```
_amavisd
_appleevents
_appowner
_appserver
_ard
_assetcache
_astris
_atsserver
_avbdeviced
_calendar
_ces
_clamav
_coreaudiod
_coremediaiod
_cvmsroot
_cvs
_cyrus
_devdocs
_devicemgr
_displaypolicyd
_distnote
_dovecot
_dovenull
_dpaudio
_eppc
_ftp
_gamecontrollerd
_geod
..
_update_sharing
_usbmuxd
_uucp
_warmd
_webauthserver
_windowserver
_www
_wwwproxy
_xcsbuildagent
_xcscredserver
_xcstest
_xserverdocs
```

the ones with a leading underscore are *service accounts* (used to establish a special user for running particular applications).  Those without a leading underscore are (almost all) user login accounts.

Some are not.  Looking at a listing, these are *not*:

com.apple.calendarserver
daemon
hadoop
macports
messagebus
named
nobody
polkitd
polkituser
postgres
pulse
svn

A couple are special well-known BSD Unix-style users (`daemon`, `nobody`, `root`), but the others are (again) service accounts created by installing a program. In your list `jenkins` is probably one of those, e.g., for the [Jenkins build-server](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/installing-jenkins-osx-yosemite.html).

Some have matches in the list of leading-underscore names (`postgres` and `_postgres`, `svn` and `_svn`) which hints that the latter may be used for "separated privileges" (see *[Why do some usernames on FreeBSD start with an underscore?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305124/why-do-some-usernames-on-freebsd-start-with-an-underscore/305134#305134)*).

Further reading:

- [What are the valid users that need to exist on Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168791/what-are-the-valid-users-that-need-to-exist-on-mac-os-x)
- [XAMPP on Mac OSX: Why running as 'daemon'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821536/xampp-on-mac-osx-why-running-as-daemon)
- ["nobody" account](https://discussions.apple.com/message/5108489#5108489)
- [Creating a service account on OS X (Yosemite)](http://pelaxa.com/blog/2015/03/17/creating-a-service-account-on-os-x-yosemite/)
- [Leopard underscore user names](http://the-mac-os-x-server-mailing-list.10970.n7.nabble.com/Leopard-underscore-user-names-td11346.html)

Comment: The accounts with a leading `_` are hidden from `System Preferences` to avoid beginners to get frightened by so many unknown "users".

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Thomas. What about following user - nobody, daemon, root, jenkins?